# assignment vs std::swap and merging and keeping duplicates in seperate object

Tags: c++, algorithm, merge, set

Say I have two `std::set<std::string>`s. The first one, `old_options`, needs to be merged with additional options, contained in `new_options`. I can't just use `std::merge` (well, I do, but not only that) because I also check for doubles and warn the user about this accordingly. To this effect, I have

```
void merge_options( set<string> &old_options, const set<string> &new_options )
{
    // find duplicates and create merged_options, a stringset containing the merged options
    // handle duplicated the way I want to
    // ...
    old_options = merged_options;
}
```

1. Is it better to use

   ```
   std::swap( merged_options, old_options );
   ```

   or the assignment I have?
2. Is there a better way to filter duplicates and return the merged `set` than consecutive calls to `std::set_intersection` and `std::set_union` to detect dupes and merge the `set`s? I know it's slower than one traversal and doing both at once, but these sets are small (performance is not critical) and I trust the Standard more than I trust myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
void merge_options( set<string> &old_options, const set<string> &new_options )
{
    for (set<string>::iterator i = new_options.begin();
         i != new_options.end(); ++i)
        if (old_options.find(*i) != old_options.end())
            warn_duplicate(*i);
        else
            old_options.insert(*i);
}
```

This is a simple O(*m* lg *n*) algorithm, where *m* = `new_options.size()` and *n* = `old_options.size()`.

Comment: simple, yes, but isn't mine the same in performance (if you neglect the factor 2, which shouldn't matter in big-O). I had a simultaneous traverse in mind, which would essentially be O(log(max(M,N)). That would really gain performance, but as Jerry says, is more complicated and perhaps not useful here. I was just making sure I'm not missing a C++ library function.

Comment: @rubenvb: A simultaneous traversal would be O(max(m,n)), I think. The difference between this and your version is 1) less allocations and copying (assuming C++03) and 2) I think mine is clearer. I don't think the standard library has a shorter way of doing this, but I must admit `<algorithm>` keeps surprising me.

Comment: ah yes, `log` is for binary search, stupid me `=s`. @Blastfurnace has a nice one too. (and `<algorithm>` keeps surprising me as well, hence the question)

Answer (score 1):

Given (as you've stated) that performance isn't critical here, I'd use the assignment and the two-pass algorithm. It's simpler and easier to understand; it's only worth using a "trick" like swap if you really need what it gains.

Writing your own algorithm wouldn't be such a bad thing, but again, unless you have a real use for the benefit it provides, I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

This is in part an answer to larsmans. There is a `remove_copy_if` algorithm that encapsulates his `for` loop into a single function. The following uses a C++0x lambda for the predicate.

```
void merge_options( set<string> &old_options, const set<string> &new_options )
{
    remove_copy_if(
        new_options.begin(),
        new_options.end(),
        inserter(old_options, old_options.end()),
        [&](const string &s) {
            return (old_options.count(s)) ? warn_duplicate(s), true : false;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, same complexity. What does the `&` in the lambda introducer do? I'm not familiar with lambdas yet.

Comment: @larsmans: It's a capture clause that allows the lambda to access variables in the enclosing scope. The `&` accesses all captured variables by reference. In this case it allows the lambda to see (and modify) the old_options set.